# jQuery Sort both ascending and descending (Not a table)

Tags: jquery, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of results by price and rating. For simplicity, I've just included 2 results: Rider's Lodge and Olina Lodge. I have written a function that sorts it one way.

How can I re-use the same function to sort my results such that clicking on the 'Sort by Price' sorts by ascending, clicking on it again sorts by descending and it toggles between the two?

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="filters">
        <p>
            <a href="javascript:sort_by_rating();">Sort by Rating</a>
            <br>
            <a href="javascript:sort_by_price();">Sort by Price</a>
        </p>
    </div>


    <div id="div_hotel_results" class="tab-pane active">
        <form id="hotel-form">
        ...
        </form>
        <div class="results-row">
            <h5>Riders Lodge</h5>
            <span class="label label-info price">$103.64</span>
            <span class="rating" data-rating="3.0">3.0</span>
        </div>

        <div class="results-row">
            <h5>Olina Lodge</h5>
            <span class="label label-info price">$99.64</span>
            <span class="rating" data-rating="2.5">2.5</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sort_by_price () {
    var sorted_list = [];
    $('.price').each(function (index) {
        sorted_list[index] = $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        sorted_list[index]['cleaned_price'] = parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
    });

    sorted_list.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a['cleaned_price'] == b['cleaned_price']) {
            return 0;
        } else if (a['cleaned_price'] > b['cleaned_price']) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    });

    $('#hotel-form').after(sorted_list);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want the function to both sort ascending, desceding AND switch between rating/price?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example. I believe you only wanted the price, not rating. I've created a variable that helps keep track on the current status of the sort. Then it sorts ascending/descending depending on that.

I also moved your event bindings outside the html.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7y9MA/3/)

**Html:**

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="filters">
        <p>
            <a class="sortByRating" href="#" >Sort by Rating</a>
            <br>
            <a class="sortByPrice" href="#">Sort by Price</a>
        </p>
    </div>


    <div id="div_hotel_results" class="tab-pane active">
        <form id="hotel-form">
        ...
        </form>
        <div class="results">
            <div class="results-row">
                <h5>Riders Lodge</h5>
                <span class="label label-info price">$103.64</span>
                <span class="rating" data-rating="3.0">3.0</span>
            </div>

            <div class="results-row">
                <h5>Olina Lodge</h5>
                <span class="label label-info price">$99.64</span>
                <span class="rating" data-rating="2.5">2.5</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var ascending = false;

$('.tab-content').on('click','.sortByPrice',function(){

    var sorted = $('.results-row').sort(function(a,b){
        return (ascending ==
               (convertToNumber($(a).find('.price').html()) < 
                convertToNumber($(b).find('.price').html()))) ? 1 : -1;
    });
    ascending = ascending ? false : true;

    $('.results').html(sorted);
});

var convertToNumber = function(value){
     return parseFloat(value.replace('$',''));
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell he's not asking for the rating one. He wants to be able to switch between ascending and descending on price. "clicking on the 'Sort by Price' sorts be ascending, clicking on it again sorts by descending and it toggles between the two?". I think we need the author to clarify this.

Comment: I think its clearly written if first line **I'm trying to sort a list of results by price and rating.**

Comment: The question is how to toggle between sorting ascending and descending. What you just wrote is what he's trying to achieve in the end but, he's not asking for a solution on that - as I understand it. Anyway we can interpret what he wants forever. He'll eventually write back. Here's a fiddle where rating also works. http://jsfiddle.net/7y9MA/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
//package algorithm.sort;

public class QuickSort 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = { 9, 2, 4, 7, 3, 7, 10 };
        printArray(x);

        int low = 0;
        int high = x.length - 1;

        quickSort(x, low, high);
        printArray(x);
    }

    public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int low, int high) {

        if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
            return;

        if (low >= high)
            return;

        //pick the pivot
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        int pivot = arr[middle];

        //make left < pivot and right > pivot
        int i = low, j = high;
        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }

            while (arr[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }

            if (i <= j) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        //recursively sort two sub parts
        if (low < j)
            quickSort(arr, low, j);

        if (high > i)
            quickSort(arr, i, high);
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] x) {
        for (int a : x)
            System.out.print(a + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```